# Convert sting input to int C#

Tags: c#, string, int

so I have to make a program that stop's when the use enter "FIN" in the console app, else the program continue. The problem is that I'm not able to convert the number given to integer after. 
Here is the code

[https://pastebin.com/USTia33i]

Cet algorithme, permet l'identifiaction de numéros de cartes de crédit ainsi que leur validation. Pour cela, 
l'utilisateur entre le numéro sous la forme ABCDEF GH IJKL MNOP, puis selon le type de carte, l'algorithme 
transforme le numéro sous la forme appropriée et fait la validation de la carte en fonction de son type.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;
using static System.Math;

namespace Partie_2_Cartes_de_crédit
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            // Numéro de carte de crédit séparé blocs
            Write("Entrez les 6 premiers chiffres de votre carte (ABCDEF) ou (FIN) pour arreter : ");
            sting abcdef = ReadLine();

            for (; ; )
            {
                /***/
                if (abcdef == "FIN") break;
                /***/
                {

                    // Numéro de carte de crédit séparé blocs         
                    Write("Entrez les 2 chiffres suivants de votre carte (GH) : ");
                    int gh = ToInt32(ReadLine());

                    Write("Entrez les 4 chiffres suivants de votre carte (IJKL) : ");
                    int ijkl = ToInt32(ReadLine());

                    Write("Entrez les 4 chiffres suivants de votre carte (MNOP) : ");
                    int mnop = ToInt32(ReadLine());

                    // Vérification pour une carte American Express
                    if (abcdef / 10000 == 34 || abcdef / 10000 == 37)
                    {
                        int abcde = abcdef / 10;        // Numéro de carte de crédit séparé blocs
                        int fghijk = abcdef % 10 * 100000 + gh * 1000 + ijkl / 10;
                        int lmnop = ijkl % 10 * 10000 + mnop;
                        WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcde + " " + fghijk + " " + lmnop +
                            " indique une carte American Express, à valider en ligne.");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // Vérification pour une carte Visa
                        int abcd = abcdef / 100;        // Numéro de carte de crédit séparé blocs
                        int efgh = abcdef % 100 * 100 + gh;

                        if (abcd / 1000 == 4)
                        {
                            WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcd + " " + efgh + " " + ijkl + " " + mnop +
                                " indique une carte Visa à valider en ligne.");
                        }
                        // Vérification pour une carte MasterCard
                        else if (abcd / 100 >= 51 && abcd / 100 <= 55)
                        {
                            WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcd + " " + efgh + " " + ijkl + " " + mnop +
                                " indique une carte MasterCard à valider en ligne.");
                        }
                        // Vérification pour une carte Sears
                        else if (abcd / 10 == 628 && abcd % 10 != 0 && efgh / 1000 != 0 && efgh / 100 % 10 != 0)
                        {
                            // Formule de Luhn
                            int i = ijkl / 1000;        // Numéro de carte de crédit séparé en chiffre
                            int j = ijkl / 100 % 10;
                            int k = ijkl / 10 % 10;
                            int l = ijkl % 10;

                            int m = mnop / 1000;
                            int n = mnop / 100 % 10;
                            int o = mnop / 10 % 10;
                            int p = mnop % 10;

                            i *= 2;
                            k *= 2;
                            m *= 2;
                            p *= 2;

                            if (i >= 10)
                            {
                                i -= 9;
                            }
                            if (k >= 10)
                            {
                                k -= 9;
                            }
                            if (m >= 10)
                            {
                                m -= 9;
                            }
                            if (p >= 10)
                            {
                                p -= 9;
                            }

                            if (i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p % 10 == 0)
                            {
                                WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcd + " " + efgh + " " + ijkl + " " + mnop +
                                    " indique une carte Sears valide.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcd + " " + efgh + " " + ijkl + " " + mnop +
                                    " indique une carte Sears invalide.");
                            }
                        }
                        // Vérification pour une carte Zellers
                        else if (abcd / 10 == 700)
                        {
                            // Formule de Luhn
                            int i = ijkl / 1000;        // Numéro de carte de crédit séparé en chiffre
                            int j = ijkl / 100 % 10;
                            int k = ijkl / 10 % 10;
                            int l = ijkl % 10;

                            int m = mnop / 1000;
                            int n = mnop / 100 % 10;
                            int o = mnop / 10 % 10;
                            int p = mnop % 10;

                            i *= 2;
                            k *= 2;
                            m *= 2;
                            p *= 2;

                            if (i >= 10)
                            {
                                i -= 9;
                            }
                            if (k >= 10)
                            {
                                k -= 9;
                            }
                            if (m >= 10)
                            {
                                m -= 9;
                            }
                            if (p >= 10)
                            {
                                p -= 9;
                            }

                            if (i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p % 10 == 0)
                            {
                                WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcd + " " + efgh + " " + ijkl + " " + mnop +
                                    " indique une carte Zellers valide.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcd + " " + efgh + " " + ijkl + " " + mnop +
                                    " indique une carte Zellers invalide.");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WriteLine("Le numéro " + abcd + " " + efgh + " " + ijkl + " " + mnop +
                                " indique une carte inconne.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to convert and store your `abcdef` as a new variable: `int input1 = ToInt32(abcdef)`.  Then later in your code use the `input1` instead of `abcdef`.

Comment: Thank you it work!

Comment: You should be down voted because of your variable names

Comment: Also, **NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER** parse user input with any `<type>.Parse` methods, **ALWAYS** use `TryParse`

Comment: Hahah the variable represent the credit card number!

Comment: @TheGeneral I agree that ``TryParse()`` is almost always what you want but I'll disagree with the amount of emphasis you express. Sometimes (only sometimes) catching the exception is just easier…

Comment: @dumetrulo i guess that was overly emphasized, could have done with a few less evers ;)

Comment: I was curious as to how this would look in a complete program with a bit more separation of concerns, so I implemented an F# version first (https://repl.it/repls/RareDeficientMicroprogramming), and translated it to C# afterwards (https://repl.it/repls/FinishedDeepAssignments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Int32.TryParse
```

returns you a bool and populate the variable, check the bool to see if it was indeed an int.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2